# Use boto3 to upload a file to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a script to upload a csv file which is in a container to S3 bucket, I copied the file to my local machine and I'm testing the script locally, but getting errors. I'm still learning everything, trying to know what part I'm missing in the script and how I can get this running and upload the file to S3,

Here's the errors:

error_1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/U12345/IdeaProjects/xxx/s3_upload.py", line 19, in <module>
    r'C:\Users\U12345\IdeaProjects\xxx\test_' + str(current_date) + '.csv')
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\U12345\\IdeaProjects\\xxx\\test.csv' -> 'C:\\Users\\U12345\\IdeaProjects\\xxx\\test_2020-04-16 10:55:41.csv'
```

error_02:

```
File "C:/Users/U12345/IdeaProjects/xxx/s3_upload.py", line 33
    response = s3_client.put_object(Body='C:\Users\U12345/IdeaProjects/xxx/test.csv',
                                        ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Another issue is I'm not very sure how to call this function, what parameter to put in the bracket, it gave me different errors.

I've been struggling with this for almost a week now, a bit frustrated, can someone gave me some help or a good example that I can follow.

Update:

error02 and the last issue have been solved, it's just the first error still not working, I've trying '/', '', with 'C:', without 'C:', all not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few things to address here so lets break it down a little bit.

1) When you call `upload_to_s3()` you need to call it with the function parameters you've declared it with, a filename and a bucket key. So it would be `upload_to_s3(filename, bucket_key)` for example.

2) It's a been a while since I used Windows & Python but ask yourself if it uses `\` instead of `/` in file paths, also make sure the file is definitely in the location you expect.

3) For the S3 upload the `Body:` is the actual data you want to upload, not the filename of the data. You have called it inside `open(...) as file` so you now have an object called `file` that represents it.

Comment: I've managed to upload the local file to S3 (without changing the name since ```os.rename```) still giving me errors, a small follow up question is what if the csv file is in a container and generated from the model that running on Fargate, how am I supposed to modify it and link with Fargate and docker?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using put_object() the wrong way. It is used to save an **'object'** on s3 & **not a file** i.e you need to first read the file content using pandas.read_csv() or something else & then replace the 'Body' part with the object obtained on reading.Something like this

```
  df= pandas.read_csv('C:\Users\U12345/IdeaProjects/xxx/test.csv')
  response = s3_client.put_object(Body=df,  
                                    Bucket=output_bucket,
                                    Key='test.csv',
                                    ACL="bucket-owner-full-control")
```

If you wish to upload the file directly, you should use

```
  s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
  s3.meta.client.upload_file('C:\Users\U12345/IdeaProjects/xxx/test.csv', output_bucket, 'test.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

in the last line

```
upload_to_s3()
```

you haven't actually given the function any parameters. inside the brackets put in the params:

```
(source_filename: str, key: str)
```

ie give the function it's filename and bucket