# File can be uploaded to S3 locally but can't within a container (Unable to locate credential)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, aws-fargate

I have a Python script to upload a file to S3, the code is the same in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247820/use-boto3-to-upload-a-file-to-s3).

I have a bash script that pass the AWS credential. The file I wanted to upload is generated from a model that running on Fargate (ina container), so I tried to run this Python script within the container to upload to S3, I've built the image, but when I run `docker run containername` it will give me error:

```
INFO:root:Uploading to S3 from test.csv to bucket_name test.csv

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Can someone gave me some hint? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you configuring the AWS SDK? Are you trying to pass accessKeyId and secret to the sdk?

Comment: Are you running this container from your local machine?

Comment: yes from my local machine @RaduDiță. I have a bash script which  I've added on the question that can pass the credentials

Comment: This will not work out of the box. You need to copy your credentials to your docker container for this to work. Using volumes should do the trick. But in Fargate this is not the case. You need to create an IAM role for your task definition and assign it. AWS will take care of using that role for any AWS API calls.

Comment: @RaduDiță can you be mor specific about the Fargate part, how I can link those with Fargate? By Terraform? I already have a Fargate role to allow it run the container, should I just add some policy to the role? is there an example or step-by-step instruction?

Comment: Yes, you need to add policies. It's hard to get a step-by-step as it depends on what resources you need. But you could add the S3 Full access managed policy from aws, to get full access to S3. But you should be more restrictive in your policies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass docker credentials you either need to mount `~/.aws/credentials` in your container

```
docker -v ~/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro
```

Or pass your credentials as env vars

```
docker run -e -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws configure get aws_access_key_id --profile profilename) -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(aws configure get aws_secret_access_key --profile profilename)
```

For the Fargate side you need to create an IAM Role and add a Policy that has access to that bucket.

This needs to be assign to the `Task Role`. This is different than the `Task Execution Role` which is used to pull the docker image. The `Task Role` is used at run time and that's where you need to add the policy for S3 access.

Comment: I solved the credential issue now, made a stupid mistake, thanks, now moving to Fargate task.

Comment: Just a quick follow up question, how can I link the Python script to Fargate? Or I don't need it at all?

Comment: You need to copy the python script to the docker image, push the image to ECR and if the script is run as part of the CMD Docker command. There shouldn't be anything else for you to configure.